# mysqli_connect(): (HY000/1045)

Tags: php, mysql, xampp

here is my code

```
    <?php
     $host="localhost";
     $dbuser="root";
     $pass="";
     $dbname="online_exam";
     $conn=mysqli_connect($host,$dbuser,$pass,$dbname);
        // echo "$conn";
         if(mysqli_connect_errno())
         {die("connection Failed!".mysqli_connect_error());
         }
?>
<html>
<body background="bg/hero8.jpg" text="white">
<table cellspacing="15px" border="0px" align="center">
          <tr></tr>
          <tr></tr>
          <tr></tr>
          <tr></tr>
          <tr></tr>
          <tr></tr>
          <tr></tr>
          <tr></tr>
          <tr></tr>
          <tr></tr>
          <tr></tr>
          <tr></tr>
          <tr></tr>
          <tr></tr>

<form action="loginS.php" method="POST">
<tr>
 <td>STUDENTS LOGIN</td></tr>
 <tr>
<td>Enter the user name:<input type="text" name="uname"></td></tr>
<tr>
<td>Enter the Password:<input type="password" name="pwd"></td></tr>
<tr><td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="LOGIN"></td></tr>

</table>
</body>
</html>
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
$uname = $_POST['uname'];
$pswd=$_POST['pwd'];

if(empty($uname) || empty($pswd))
{echo"OOPs! Your are suppose to not leave any of the constrains empty ";}
else{
    $sql="SELECT * FROM student WHERE Email='{$uname}'AND Pass='{$pswd}';"; //Q_no, Ques, Op_1, Op_2, Op_3, Op_4, Ans
                    $res=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
                    if(!$res){
                        //die("query failed".mysqli_error($conn));
                        echo "User name or password is wrong";

                    }
                    else{$flag=0;
                        while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($res)){

                            //$course = $row['Course'];                                     //$question_array[$i]=$row['Ques'];
                            $name = $row['Name'];
                            $lastresult= $row['Lastresult'];
                            $USN=$row['USN'];
                            $flag=1;

                    }   
                        if($flag==0)
                        {echo "Wrong Password or Username";
                            exit;}
                         session_start();
                            $_SESSION['myValue']=$lastresult;
                            $_SESSION['myValue1']=$name;
                            $_SESSION['myValue2']=$USN;

                            header("Location: Student_menu.php");
                            exit;
                    }
}   
}

?>
```

my error occurs in line 6

I am using XAMPP

> Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user
>   'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES) in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\xampp\DBMS\loginS.php on line 6 connection
>   Failed!Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Comment: `Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' `

Comment: Are you sure your root account does not need a password?

Comment: Try with default password "root" may be it helps you , pass value in password field like $pass="root"

Comment: Have you noticed the part where it says, `(using password: YES)`? And then look at your code `$pass="";`, so the same question as others have asked, are you sure that it does not take in a password?

Comment: @Srinabh Did this get resolved? Did you sort out the password issue?